# Property with @ManyToOne relation : How to make a relative counter?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having two entities with parent/child relation (user->comments).

I want the child entity to have a "relativeCounter" property with two behaviors :

- it increment by 1 every time its added
- it restart at 1 every time its the first parent's child

What is the best way to formalize those contraints with Doctrine Annotations ?

Comment: You cannot do it with annotations, but you can do it in the setters of the parent and child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably go with EventSubscriber on this. Subscribe to `preUpdate` event and check for the conditions you mentioned.